# How can I create an exe to start another exe as administrator with credentials?

Tags: windows, exe, credentials, administrator

I need to create an exe (1) or something else that opens an exe (2) (which only works as an administrator) and saving the administrator credentials inside the exe (1) so that users can't see the credentials. A batch file is useless because users can edit it and see the credentials. A shortcut is useless too because users can edit it and use it to open something else.

Comment: if you launch using admin, anything 'it' launches will be admin, conversely package it up as service, on windows it can run as 'system' which has higher permissions than admin.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, and not a programming-related problem at that. Explain the scenario. So you have lower-privileged users who have to run a certain elevated executable, without providing credentials? Do they actually have to manually start this program, or are other solutions also an option?

Comment: There are few users who need to use a 3D printer using printer software that has a problem, it can only be started as Administrator. We tried to contact the producer but he said the software can't be modified. So I need something that allows users to use that software without knowing the password.